# postgres: Combining filter() with a percentile_cont()

Tags: postgresql

Trying to use a `filter()` clause within a call to `percentile_const` and I am not sure I can do this. Is there a way? Here's the example query:

```
select
    count(*) as n1,
    count(*) filter(where ha >= 0) as n2,
    percentile_cont(.9) within group (order by es asc) as p1,
    percentile_cont(.9) filter (where ha >= 0) within group (order by es asc) as p2
from mytable where mypid = 123;
```

The query works fine without the `p2` call of course, but you can see what I want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `filter` needs to go after the `within group` part:

```
select
    count(*) as n1,
    count(*) filter(where ha >= 0) as n2,
    percentile_cont(.9) within group (order by es asc) as p1,
    percentile_cont(.9) within group (order by es asc) filter (where ha >= 0) as p2
from mytable 
where mypid = 123;
```